# Chinese font and bold text behavior

Tags: html, css, cjk

My website contains Chinese and English on the same page.

I have some Chinese text (图像测试评估 （记忆-开发右脑)) which has font-size: 34px.

With this font size, some words are bold and others are normal.

Is there some doctype or something else which could resolve this issue? I require that all the words should be normal size unless I explicitly make them bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `content-language` `meta` tag resolved the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="zh" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The characters are probably not bold but from another font, with characteristics that make them look bold when compared with another font. The browser’s default font does not contain all the characters used in the text, so the browser picks them up from other fonts.

Setting the content language may appear to help, because it affects the browser’s choice of default font in some browsers. It is not reliable, though, since browsers may ignore the information, so you should additionally set the text font.

Thus, find out some widely available fonts that cover all the characters you need and are stylistically acceptable for you page. Specify a list of the fonts, in order of preference, in a CSS declaration like `body { font-family: DFKai-SB, Microsoft JhengHei, MingLiU, Apple LiSung }` if traditional Chinese is used (you would need to find suitable font[s] commonly available on Linux and containing Chinese characters and add them to the list to stay on the safe side).

Comment: Thank you for the details. I need this information again and upon revist to my qustion i read this. I will use it.